# How to Bind a Command to a CheckBox

Tags: wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I'm trying to bind the checkbox checkchange event to a command - MVVM
Why doesn't this work? or do anything while the same works on button?

```
<CheckBox x:Name="radRefresh" IsChecked="{BindingREADY, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding Refresh_Command}" Content=" Refresh "  Margin="10,25,0,0"  />

<Button Command="{Binding Refresh_Command}" />
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work...

`<i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
       <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=YourCommand,Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=YourCheckBox}"></cmd:EventToCommand>
         </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>`

where i is

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Add namespace for cmd

```
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```

This is one of the preferred ways for MVVM if you are utilizing the MVVMLight Framework.

Comment: what is the cmd namespace, isn't it from the MVVM Light toolkit?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The thing is, not everybody is using MVVM Light (I prefer Prism) so calling it "the only preferred way" is a bit strong :-)

Comment: Some examples of how to do this without MVVM Light can be found [here](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/5495).

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to bind it to an event.
All you need to do is bind IsChecked to a boolean dependency property, and do whatever logic you'd like on its setter.

Like this -

```
<CheckBox x:Name="radRefresh" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content=" Refresh "  Margin="10,25,0,0"  />
```

This xaml should bind you to this property on the VM

```
  public bool IsChecked
  {
      get
      {
          return isChecked;
      }
      set
      {
          isChecked = value;
          NotifyPropertChanged("IsChecked");

          //Add any logic you'd like here
       }
   }
```

Comment: Hi Orchestraor, i like your answer, kindly clear my on couple of things.You said, i need to bind my property to a Dependency property, so first i have to create a dependency property in my VM? and do i need to set the Content="Refresh" property or it could do without refreshing it?

Comment: Hi Manav, Yes you would have to create a property just like I specified in the code. I call it a dependency property because it raises the NotifyPropertChanged event. that's why your ViewModel must implement the INotifyPropertChanged interface. You don't need to set any other property besides the "IsChecked" property, I only added them because they existed in Jon's question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple situation:

1. Bind the CheckBox.IsChecked to a boolean value in your ViewModel.
2. In your viewmodel, subscribe to the property changed event and watch for the boolean value to change.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because only a handful of controls (`Button`, `MenuItem` of the top of my head) implement the functionality to directly bind commands.

If you need to bind to a control, I would recommend creating a `UserControl` that executes the ViewModel's command when the CheckBox's property `IsChecked` is changed in codebehind.